# Excel Convert Now() to a Number to compare against another Number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010

I am trying to use some logic in a spreadsheet without any macros.

First I have a sinle cell that gives the date and time. I then used the custom format on that cell to just show the "h". So only hour numbers 1 through 24 appear in this cell. (e.g. at 3:20 p.m. I get 15 in the cell). (Cell # A:1)

```
=now()
```

Second, I have a separate single column with 24 rows numbered 1-24 (Cell #'s B1:B24)

I have a third column that has logic that states "Night" shift" for numbers 23 & 0-6; "Day Shift" for numbers 7-14; and "Mid Shift" for numbers 15-22)      (Cell #'s C1:C24)

```
=if($A$1=B1,"Night Shift","")
```

However, the third columns all appear blank even tough one should appear. I tried changing A1 using text(A1,"#") but I get the serial number. Is there an easy way to  dynamically have a value in column C  show what shift  based off the hour of the day in cell A1. Column D simply concatenates all 24 cells since there will only be one number ever. (Cell # D1). Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `LOOKUP` formula to return the shift based on a time/date value in A1, e.g.

`=LOOKUP(HOUR(A1),{0,7,15,23;"Night","Day","Mid","Night"})&" Shift"`

Answer (score 1):

Changing the format of the cell containing the date and time does nothing to the actual contents of the cell.  It will still contain a value such as 43706.75 (number of days and fractions of days since 1/1/1900).

If what you want to do is determine the shift for the date/time in A1, you could use a formula like:

```
=IF(AND(HOUR(A1)>=7,HOUR(A1)<15),"Day Shift",IF(AND(HOUR(A1)>=15,HOUR(A1)<23),"Mid Shift","Night Shift"))
```

And similar logic if you need to apply different multipliers for the salary.

If you need something else, be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

By doing `=now()` without any formatting you get the Date and the Time. Then in cell A2 do

```
=(A1-INT(A1))*24
```

Then in cell A3 do

```
=INT(A2)
```

This gives you the hour number extracted from a date format so a comparison can be made in column C against the numbers in column B. Thanks.